# Can I Use 2 foreach from variable database in laravel?

Tags: php, loops, laravel-5, controller, laravel-blade

[image]

I Want make foreach in behind loping

```
$aproval = Aproval_position::get();
$user = User::get();
return view('authentication.index_aproval', compact('user','aproval'));
```

this view blade

```
@foreach($aproval as $approv)
    <label for="" class="col-lg-3">{{ $approv->name_matrix  }}</label>                                 
    <select>
        @foreach($user as $user)
            <option value="">{{ $user->name }}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select> 
@endforeach
```

but when I try to use foreach user inside looping aproval thats error,
I want use User foreach table 2x or more but can't,
can you give me recomended way to use that ?

Comment: what error are you facing?

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
@foreach($user as $user)
   <option value="">{{ $user->name }}</option>
@endforeach
```

To this:

```
@foreach($user as $item)
   <option value="">{{ $item->name }}</option>
@endforeach
```

I hope that would solve your problem.

Comment: when I use @foreach($user as $item) user two time in one view its error,